# Consider $f_n(x)={x^n-x^{3n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A. For what values of x is the function series is point-wise convergent, and to what function?

B. For what values of x is the series uniform convergence?

My answers in the textbook are:

A. As $n\to \infty$, $f_{n \to \infty}x=0$ for $x \in [-1,1]$. Why is it true? I mean how to calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n-x^{3n}$?

B. for $x\in [-r,r]$ and $r<1$.

Any explanations?

Comment: Hint: look at the limit of a sum or product of function. $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^{2n})$

Comment: If $|a|\le 1$ then what can be said about $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n$?

Comment: The B statement means absolutely nothing... $r<1$ is in contradiction with $\forall r\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question A**

The question B answers the question A for all $x\in]-1,1[$, since you can choose $r$ such that $|x|\leq r<1$, and uniform convergence of $[-r,r]$ implies pointwise convergence.

You can prove it directly anyway, with the same argument: for $x$ with $|x|<1$,

$$|f_n(x)|=|x^n(1-x^{2n})|\leq |x|^n \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

And $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$, so again there is pointwise convergence (to zero), for $x=\pm1$.

Hence $f_n$ converges to $f\equiv0$ on $[-1,1]$, *pointwise*.

**Question B**

If $0<r<1$, and $|x|\leq r$, then

$$|f_n(x)|=|x^n(1-x^{2n})|\leq|x^n|\leq r^n$$

Hence

$$\sup_{x\in[-r,r]} |f(x)|\leq r^n \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

So there is indeed uniform convergence on $[-r,r]$.

However, you have also to prove convergence is not uniform on the whole interval $[-1,1]$. To achieve this, let's find minimum and maximum values of $f$, so first differentiate:

$$f'(x)=nx^{n-1}-3nx^{3n-1}$$

And $f'(x)=0$ iff

$$nx^{n-1}=3nx^{3n-1}$$
$$x^{2n}=\frac13$$
$$x=\pm\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac1{2n}}$$

Now, compute value of $f$ for these $x$:

$$f\left(\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac1{2n}}\right)=\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{n}{2n}}-\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{3n}{2n}}=\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$f\left(-\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac1{2n}}\right)=(-1)^n\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{n}{2n}}-(-1)^{3n}\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{3n}{2n}}=(-1)^n\left(\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$

Both are constant in absolute value, so you have two sequences of numbers,

$$u_n=\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac1{2n}}$$
$$v_n=-\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac1{2n}}$$

With $u_n\rightarrow1$, $v_n\rightarrow-1$, and yet $f_n(u_n)\not\rightarrow0$, $f_n(v_n)\not\rightarrow0$. Hence the sequence $f_n$ can't converge uniformly to $f\equiv0$ on $[-1,1]$.